# Annualized Excess Return

Tags: finance

I have been given the following formula to calculated Annualized excess return:

```
Annualized excess return = (1+Monthly excess return)^12-1
```

The answer is provided (by the text) as AER = (1-.0036)^12-1 = 4.41%

When I calculate this I get:

```
 (1-.0036)^12 = 0.957645178 therefore (1-.0036)^12 - 1 = -0.042354822
```

On this basis I think the answer should be -4.23% and not 4.41%? Can anyone help me confirm or contradict this assertion?

Comment: Plus versus minus: $(1+.0036)^{12}=1.044066...\approx1.0441$ --> return of $4.41\%$. Either you got the sign wrong or there is a typo in the source you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks Richard - it is a typo in the source. I should have seen it in the formula which correctly specifies it.

Comment: I tried, but not allowed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plus versus minus: $(1+.0036)^{12}=1.044066...≈1.0441\rightarrow$ return of $4.41\%$.
Either you got the sign wrong or there is a typo in the source you are referring to.